# How to deal with route dispatching in CherrPy?

Tags: python, routes, cherrypy

I'm having a big problem in managing my routes in a CherrPy project.

My project is moduled as such:

```
project-name/lib/app-name1
                /app-name2
```

What I would want is this:
1. All the routes to be exclusive to their apps, with a primary route dispatcher outside of the lib.

1. Matching of urls using MethodDispatcher. I should directly match with login method of User View.

What I've is this:

```
class Root(object):
    pass

root = Root()

root.user = UserView()
#root.user.login = UserView()
d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.connect('login', '/user/login', controller=root.user, action='login')
#root.user.login = UserView()

conf = {
    'global': {
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
        'server.socket_port': 8000,
    },
    '/': {
        'request.dispatch': d,
    },
}


cherrypy.quickstart(root, '/', conf
```

)

Though I'm terribly failing in hitting the login function of UserView contoller.

It only works if I do root.user.login  = UserView(), but that doesn't call the login function of the UserView class. That calls the Post function of the UserView class.

So, it's a bit messed up right now and it would be nice to have some clarity.

a url would look like: localhost/user/login?params

Comment: Something wrong must be with `UserView` class as it seems to be working for me.